# Undefined is not a function foreach loop

Tags: javascript, function, foreach

I would like to have a function run for every item in an array. The array is different every time but for this I will just use an example array. It keeps saying undefined is not a function at the, I assume undefined being foreachfunction. Whats the solution to this?

```
const bar1beats = [0.5, 1, 2.5]
generate.addEventListener('click', generateclick)


function generateclick(){

// error line
  bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction());

    function foreachfunction(item, index){

    let interval = intervals[Math.floor(Math.random() * intervals.length)]
    interval();
    if(interval == fifthfunction){
    findnotefifth()
    }
    if(interval == fourthfunction){
    findnotefourth()
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't call the function? Why not instead just pass it in? `bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction);`

Comment: _" I assume undefined being foreachfunction"_ - That would be easy to check with some basic debugging, and should have been done _before_ asking us.

Comment: Looks like you already know the solution, because it's the same as in: `.addEventListener('click', generateclick)`

Answer (score 0):

You are basically giving `forEach` `undefined` instead of your function. As you call it what will pass the return value of `foreachfunction`.

To fix it remove the parenthesis:

```js
function generateclick(){

  // note I removed the parenthesis.
  bar1beats.forEach(foreachfunction);

    function foreachfunction(item, index){

    let interval = intervals[Math.floor(Math.random() * intervals.length)]
    interval();
    if(interval == fifthfunction){
    findnotefifth()
    }
    if(interval == fourthfunction){
    findnotefourth()
    }

}
```